# Integration of Zoho CRM and Moodle

Tags: integration, crm, moodle, zoho

I am looking to do an integration of Zoho CRM and Moodle, and have the following questions:

1. Are there any APIs or plugins that already exist, which make the integration simple?
2. Can actions be triggered on flow of data from CRM to Moodle? Ex: If I create a student record on Zoho CRM, can I automatically create a student login and pswd on Moodle and trigger a mail with this information to the student?

Comment: Zoho & Dynamics CRM are two different products :)

Comment: If you have ZoHo then there'sa plugin specifically for this...

https://marketplace.zoho.com/crm/moodle#overview

HTH

Dave